# Prove that the series is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone please help me prove that this series is convergent?

The problem is I don't know what to do with sin.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^n \sin{\frac{\pi}{3^n}} $$

Comment: As is, this question does not appear to be bad and does not seem as though it should have downvotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $\sin x<x$ for $x>0$ we can estimate
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n\sin(\pi/3^n)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^n\frac{\pi}{3^n}.
$$
The RHS is finite by the geometric series so our (positive) series is convergent.

Comment: Simply nice answer, and your profile pic is nice btw.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thank you! ^^ It's from _Steins;Gate_. I won't be able to answer with my profile pic next time someone ask for a nice proof of the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers, but I love that anime! ;)

Comment: XD If you are interested, I have a post concerning the sum of the [first $n^p$ numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035188/methods-to-compute-sum-k-1nkp-without-faulhabers-formula), if you think you'll be interested.

Comment: @SimpleArt Indeed I am interested!! 0.0 I happen to be these days studying summation methods, and I didn't know about Faulhaber's formula beyond the natural-exponent case. I've got hooked on the subject (apparently) the last 4 hours, so thank you for inviting me into it. =) I'll keep track of your question!

Comment: lol, you're welcomed any time, and I do hope you find some amazing answers.  (and I don't think we do Faulhaber's formula beyond the natural-exponent case...? O_o)

Comment: @SimpleArt Check [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X06008791). It is an asymptotic result but still seemed like a good starting point (and after having a view at the proof of the main theorem and notice that it used some of the theory I am studying these days I couldn't help to work it out).

Comment: You can make any number of asymptotic formulas for such.  If I may point out, a combination of different [zeta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zeta_functions) should do the job.  Mainly the Riemann zeta and Hurwitz zeta.

Comment: @SimpleArt I am aware that asymptotic estimations often don't give much information to come up with a useful formula for the finite case. In fact before starting reading that article I skipped some sources that exactly --as you say-- used zeta functions to approach the subject, but the one I read seemed to me like a good way to get-to-know the topic. If it turns out to be a good starting point to think about, then perfect, but anyway It was fun to work out! =)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the root test.

Let $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} |2^n\sin(\frac{\pi}{3^n})|^{\frac{1}{n}}.$
Then $L = \lim_{n \to \infty} (2^n\sin(\frac{\pi}{3^n}))^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} 2\sin(\frac{\pi}{3^n})^{\frac{1}{n}} = 0$, so the series converges by root test.

Comment: @OlivierOloa, the limit actually turns out to be $1/3$

Comment: $2/3$, rather, with the inclusion of the factor of $2$

Comment: @teadawg1337 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\sin(X)\sim X \;(X\to 0)$$

$$\implies 2^n\sin(\frac{\pi}{3^n})\sim (\frac{2}{3})^n\;(n\to+\infty)$$

$\implies \sum 2^n\sin(\frac{\pi}{3^n})$ is convergent since the geometric series $\sum (\frac{2}{3})^n$ is positive and convergent.