# Finding the partial sum of n(n+1)

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How do I prove that $\sum_{j=1}^n j(j+1) = \frac 13n(n+1)(n+2)$ without using induction?

Is there a proof like the classic one for $\sum_{j=1}^n j^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$?

Comment: Which "classic proof" of $\sum_{j=1}^nj^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$?

Comment: I'll try to make it in edit to this reply: new to this place and latex and a novice. It's the one where you start by taking $(k+1)^3 = k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k +1$, subtract k^3 from both sides, take the sum of it for n = (1,2,3,...,n) and do some algebra.

Comment: Personally, I think that method is very tedious in comparison to my below answer.  But do what you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).  It can easily be seen from it that

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{j(j+1)}2=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}6$$

Multiplying both sides by $2$, we get

$$\sum_{j=1}^nj(j+1)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}3$$

In general, the Hockey-stick identity lets us say that

$$\sum_{j=1}^nj(j+1)(j+2)\dots(j+p)=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+p)(n+p+1)}{p+2}$$

Answer (score 5):

Use *physics*:

The body consists of equal particles arranged into a triangle:
[image]
(Particles are placed in a squared net, so the horizontal distance between adjacent *columns* is $1$.)

Now compute its *[torque (moment of force = distance $\times$ force)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque)* caused by the gravitational force, related to the *leftmost (red) point* by two methods:

**Method 1.** *As the sum of torques of its parts:* Add torques of individual particles (grouped by columns).
[image]

The result is $$\ 0 \cdot 1\ +\ 1\ \cdot 2\ + \ 2 \cdot 3\ + \ \dots + \ n(n+1).$$

**Method 2.** *As torque of the whole body:* Multiply the distance to the *center of its mass* by the gravitational force of the whole body:

[image]
Since the gravitational force of the whole body is the sum of gravitational forces of all its particles, the  result is $$\left(\frac {2n} 3\right) \cdot (1 + 2 + \dots + n + 1) = \frac 2 3 n \frac {(n+1)(n+2)} 2 = \frac 1 3 n(n+1)(n+2).$$

As both method must give the same result, you obtain the given formula.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$f(r)=r(r+1)(r+2)$$

After simplification, $$f(r)-f(r-1)=3r(r+1)$$

Now apply a $\Sigma$ sign to both sides and we have a telescoping series which gives $$n(n+1)(n+2)=3\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+1)$$ and the result follows.