# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1^k+2^k+...+n^k}{n^k}-\frac{n}{k+1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

For some fixed natural $k$, we need to find the limit. I have been trying to solve this question in so many different ways now.. I will just outline one here. This should be solvable with the [Stolz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

My most recent idea was to treat the two terms separately, and first find the limit of the leftmost term. Then hopefully our limit is something that will take out the $n$ in the second term from the numerator. That is not the case...

Let's define $\tilde{x}_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i^k$, our numerator. Then $\tilde{y}_n = n^k$ will be our defnominator. We have that $\frac{x_n - x_{n-1}}{y_n - y_{n-1}} = \frac{n^k}{n^k - (n-1)^{k-1}}$, using binomial expansion or simply taking out the $n^k$, we see that this thing goes to plus infinity...

If I incorporate the second term in the original equation in my computations. Then I get that this difference ($\frac{x_n - x_{n-1}}{y_n - y_{n-1}}$) is also infinite: $$\frac{(1-n)(1-(1-1/n)^k)+k}{(k+1)(1-(1-1/n)^k}$$

So I am lost as to how to approach this problem now.

Comment: Possible typos: the denominator is $n^{k+1}$ not $n^k$, and $y_n-y_{n-1}$ still has the same exponent $k+1$, not two different ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \frac{(k+1)\cdot(1+\ldots+n^k)-n^{k+1}}{(k+1)\cdot n^k} = \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty} \frac{(k+1)\cdot (n+1)^{k}+n^{k+1} - (n+1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)\cdot((n+1)^k - n^k)} = \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} \frac{n^{k-1} \cdot (k(k+1))/2}{n^{k-1} \cdot k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

The first equality is due to Stoltz Cesaro's Theorem, while in the second one I am just considering the highest power in $n$ since they are polynomials.

I hope now it is correct!

Comment: You are applying Stolz to $k$, while the limit is as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Not really, but it is still wrong! I'm trying to solve it!

Comment: Edited! Is it correct now?

Comment: how do you go from the LHS first line to RHS? Can you expand a little bit, please? Thank you

Comment: I am using Stolts Cesaro with $a_n = (k+1)(1+\ldots+n^k)-n^{k+1}$ and $b_n = (k+1)n^k$ since $b_n$ is increasing and $b_n \to +\infty$

Comment: @LucaMac Yes, everything O.K.

Comment: I need to explore my previous solution, as I was solving just like you (almost). In your first step I would also take out $(k+1)/(k+1)$ from fraction and then that would lead me to infinity. I must have been making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: How do you deal with $((n+1)^k-n^k)$ in denominator. I have: $(n^k-n^k + \mathcal{O}(n^{k-1}))$

Comment: It's $n^k-n^k + kn^{k-1} + O(n^{k-2})$

Comment: Would you mind writing out more steps between the second and the third steps, please?

Comment: Use Newton's expansion for $(n+1)^k = n^k + kn^{k-1} + O(n^{k-2})$ and $(n+1)^{k+1}=n^{k+1} + (k+1)n^k + k(k+1)/2 \cdot n^{k-1} + O(n^{k-2})$. Just put them in the limit and it should be clear

Answer (score 2):

I am giving you a outline as to how approach the problem. The first term can be expressed as a definite integral by multiplying $n$ and dividing by it.  The integral evaluates to $\frac{n}{k+1}$. So you get the answer as $\frac{1}{2}$ .

Comment: It is easy to see that for $k=1$ the limit is $1/2$. The integral evaluates to $n/(k+1)+O(1)$.

Comment: Integrals are not necessary to solve this problem. I would like to know an outline for a solution that does not involve them. Thank you

Comment: @JuliánAguirre  You are right.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without Stoltz Cesaro's theorem, using generalized hrmonic numbers
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^k=H_n^{(-k)}$$ Using the asymptotics
$$H_n^{(-k)}=n^k \left(\frac{n}{k+1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{k}{12
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)+\zeta (-k)$$
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^k}{n^k}=\left(\frac{n}{k+1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{k}{12
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)+n^{-k} \zeta (-k)$$
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n i^k}{n^k}-\frac{n}{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{k}{12
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)+n^{-k} \zeta (-k)$$

For illustration purposes, let us try using $k=5$ and $n=50$, the exact value should be $ \frac{762499}{1500000}\approx 0.5083326667$ while the expansion would give $\frac{40031249999}{78750000000}\approx  0.5083333333$$
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x) =x^k$ and use the following lemma

> **Lemma**: If $f\in C^{1}[0,1] $ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-n\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx=\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{2}$$
>   ([proof available here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149174/72031))

The desired limit here is equal to $(f(1)-f(0))/2=1/2$.

If $k$ is a natural number then the proof is not that difficult and [one can prove that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2074938/72031) $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^k=\frac{n^{k+1}}{k+1}+\frac{n^{k}}{2}+P(n)$$ where $P(n) $ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree less than $k$. The desired limit is then obviously $1/2$.