# Finding the mistake in the evaluation of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1^k+2^k+...+n^k}{n^k}-\frac{n}{k+1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

This question is linked to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2941904/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-frac1k2k-nknk-fracnk1) since I am not able to spot my error.

Let $\tilde{x}_n = (k+1)(1^k + ... + n^k) - n^{k+1}$, $\tilde{x}_{n-1} = (k+1)(1^k + ... + (n-1)^k) - (n-1)^{k+1}$. Then, $\tilde{x}_n - \tilde{x}_{n-1} = (k+1)n^k - n^{k+1} + (n-1)^{k+1}$. And the denominator will be $(k+1)(n^k - (n-1)^k)$. Therefore, need to find limit of

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(k+1)n^k - n^{k+1} - (n+1)^{k+1}}{(k+1)(n^k - (n-1)^k)}$$

Here is my solution:

[image]

Comment: What is your question, precisely?

Comment: Where is the mistake here. Because when I take out the $n^{k-1}$ out of the numerator and denominator, my numerator grows to infinity. And so I cannot show that the limit is $1/2$

Comment: You evaluate the numerator correctly at one place and then write it again wrongly. The right numerator is your first one with $+(n-1)^{k+1}$ at the end. You have written it wrongly as $-(n+1)^{k+1}$.