# How do we solve this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$S= 1\times(1) + 2\times(1+2) + 3\times(1+2+3) +\dots+ n\times(1+2+3+\dots+n)$$

Comment: $S =\sum \frac{n(n+1)}{2}n$.

Comment: Hint: $1+2+\dots+n=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need three formulas. The sum of the $n$ first numbers, the sum of the $n$ first squares and the sum of the $n$ first cubes:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n j=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^n j^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^n j^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}4$$

Now, 
$$\sum_{j=1}^nj\sum_{k=1}^jk=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{j^2(j+1)}2=\frac12\left(\sum_{j=1}^nj^3+\sum_{j=1}^nj^2\right)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}+\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}8$$

hence $$S=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(3n+1)}{24}$$

Comment: Good job . Nice solution

Answer (score 2):

First, notice that $1+2+3+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$

Then notice that

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk\frac{k(k+1)}2=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^nk^3+k^2=\frac12\left(\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2+\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\right)$$

hence $$S=\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(3n+1)}{24}$$

For more information as to how to derive these formulas, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035188/methods-to-compute-sum-k-1nkp-without-faulhabers-formula).

Comment: @Did Thank you lol.  :D