# A formula for $1^m+2^m+3^m+\ldots+n^m$ using binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

It is known that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^1=\binom{n+1}{2}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=\binom{n+1}{2}+2\binom{n+1}{3}
$$
Is there a formula for
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^m,
$$
where $m$ is a positive integers, using binomial coefficients of the form $\binom{n+1}{k}$ ?

Comment: See, for instance, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fw1kRz83Fj0) by Mathologer.

Comment: Yes the sum is stricly correlated to binomial coefficients.

Comment: [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

Comment: yeah, that's correct, oops.

Comment: Thanks, but where Faulhtaber's formula uses  the coefficients $\binom{n+1}{k}$ ?

Comment: Still, if you take $p=2$ you do not get the same identity asked. I want to express the sum using expressions of the form $\binom{n+1}{k}$

Comment: I see. Faulhaber's formula expresses the sum as a polynom in $\binom{n+1}2$. Perhaps this can be transformed into $\binom{n+1}k$'s using binomial identities.

Comment: I believe that the third approach in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2044774) might answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note
$$
x^m  = \sum_{k=0}^m S_{m,k}\binom{x}{k}
\tag1$$
where
$$
S_{m,k} = S_2(m,k) k!
$$
and $S_2(m,k)$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

For $m \ge 1$ we have $S_2(m,0) = 0$, so
$$
x^m  = \sum_{k=1}^m S_{m,k}\binom{x}{k}
\tag2$$
For example
$$
x^5 = \binom{x}{1} +30\binom{x}{2} +150\binom{x}{3} +240\binom{x}{4} +120\binom{x}{5}
$$

From $(2)$ we get
$$
\sum_{x=1}^{n-1} x^m = \sum_{x=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^m S_{m,k}\binom{x}{k}
= \sum_{k=1}^m S_{m,k} \sum_{x=1}^n \binom{x}{k}
\tag3$$
Now
$$
\sum_{x=1}^n \binom{x}{k} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}\qquad\text{if } k \ge 1
$$
so from $(3)$ we have **our answer**:  if $m \ge 1$ then
$$
\sum_{x=1}^{n} x^m = \sum_{k=1}^m S_{m,k} \binom{n+1}{k+1} 
\tag4$$

> Recall:
> $S_{m,k} = S_2(m,k) k!$
> where $S_2(m,k)$ is the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

For example,
$$
\sum_{x=1}^n x^5 = \binom{n+1}{2} +30\binom{n+1}{3} +150\binom{n+1}{4} +240\binom{n+1}{5} +120\binom{n+1}{6}
$$